# NoSQL or RDBMS with MPP architecture like redshift or azure warehouse for data processing

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift, rdbms

i have a problem where in i need to store the users's address data which can come from different vendors in different format. once i have the data i need to do some cleaning and wrinkling and run the de-duplication process to get the clean structured data. once the data is clean, i may have to pick the different attributes of address from different vendors based on some complex logic which is not defined yet. my question is

1) which database i should use i.e. NOSQL database family like document/keyvalue/dynamoDB etc or RDBMS with MPP database like redshift or azure data warehouse

2) NOSQL DB like mongoDB provide the flexibility of schema but at the same time the queries or de-duplication process is not something inbuilt for these databases.

if anyone can guide me on this i shell be very thankful for him

Thanks
Atul

Comment: Are we talking about 10,000 addresses, 10M, 10B? Where are you hosting it, Azure, AWS, Google, or on-premises? Do you want platform-as-a-service, or hosting the database yourself?

Comment: Definately more them 10b. We are using the aws environment